# How to keep track of attempts in a JavaScript guess-the-number game

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

My goal is to keep track of the attempts made in the game. This is my code so far.

I have edited this post to understand difference between count = 0 and count = 1.

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1

let result = document.querySelector(".result")
let attempt = document.getElementById("attempt")
let button = document.getElementById("button")
let guess = document.getElementById("guess")
let count = 1

button.addEventListener("click", checkGuess)

function checkGuess() {
    let guessValue = document.getElementById("guess").value;
    
    if (guessValue < randomNumber) {
       attempt.innerHTML = "Attempt n: " + count
        result.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low";
        count++
    } else if (guessValue > randomNumber) {
        attempt.innerHTML = "Attempt n: " + count
        result.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high";
        count++
    } else {
        attempt.innerHTML = "Attempt n: " + count
        result.innerHTML = "You guessed correctly in " + count++ + " 
        attempts";
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Guess the number</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>GUESS A NUMBER:</h1>
  <p>Enter a guess:</p>
  <input type="number" id="guess">
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="button">
  <div>
    <p class="attempt"></p>
    <p class="result"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I can't understand why `attempt.innerHTML` won't work. It doesn't show up on the page like "result" does.

Comment: `let attempt = 1`, this creates a variable called `attempt` in your function which is set to a number.

Comment: OH what a silly mistake!!! I was confusing the variable with the count! HA. Thank you!

Comment: You have a variable called `attempt` outside your function which references a HTML element, but you also have a variables called `attempt` inside your function which is a number. Doing `attempt.innerHTML` is like doing `(1).innerHTML` if `attempt` is 1

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a global attempt variable outside the function which holds the html element and then you are declaring a local attempt variable in your function which will always be 1.

Declare a counter outside the function and then increment it everytime your function is called.

Also in your answer you are only incrementing the count and updating the attempt.innerHTML inside your if else block under specific conditions. You want to move this code outside of the if else block so it updates on every guess.

```
attemptCounter++
attempt.innerHTML = "Attempt n: " + attemptCounter
```

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1

let result = document.querySelector(".result")
let button = document.getElementById("button")
let guess = document.getElementById("guess")

let attempt = document.querySelector(".attempt")
let attemptCounter = 0

button.addEventListener("click", checkGuess)

function checkGuess() {
    let guessValue = document.getElementById("guess").value
    // Increment Attempts by 1
    attemptCounter++
    attempt.innerHTML = "Attempt n: " + attemptCounter

    if (guessValue < randomNumber) {
       result.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low";
    } else if (guessValue > randomNumber) {
       result.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high";
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "You guessed correctly";
    }
}
```

```html
  <h1>GUESS A NUMBER:</h1>
  <p>Enter a guess:</p>
  <input type="number" id="guess">
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="button">
  <div>
    <p class="attempt"></p>
    <p class="result"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not strictly related to this question but why is the counter, if defined inside the function, always 1? Still have to understand the difference between global and local variables clearly. Also, one suggestion to this post - counter should start at 1, otherwise the first attempt is 0.

Comment: When the app loads the counter should be 0 because the user has never made an attempt. Only when they click the button will you want to increment the attemptCount. When you have `let counter = 1` inside the function you are always setting a new variable everytime the checkGuess() function runs and since you set it to 1 it will always be 1

Comment: @GraceP it's always 1 because every time you call the function you redefine it as one prior to your if else statements. When you move the variable outside of the function, every time the function is called it instead references the already existing variable instead of creating a new one

Comment: @GraceP I added a code snippet for you so you can see it working in action, hope this helps

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane you're right about the user never making an attempt hence the counter should be 0. But in my now working game, the attempt only shows after the user clicks on submit. That's why I still think the counter should start at 1. Thanks to you and Zachary for the explanation about the variable inside/outside the function. Incredibly useful!

Comment: The attempt only shows after the user makes a guess in my snippet as well. You are only displaying the HTML for the counter when a user clicks the guess. What you are doing with attemptCounter = 0 is just setting the initial variable. If you change it to 1 in my snippet to start, when the user clicks your attempt counter will display for the first time and show 2

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane That's not what it shows for me O.O why?? I'll update the code up here to let you see what I have now.

Comment: @GraceP because you are updating the counter AFTER calling innerHTML that is why you need to start your counter at 1. If you look at my code snippet I am calling the attemptCounter++ first and then updating the innerHTML after this increment. Additionally you dont need to have the attemptCounter++ and the innerHTML update in all the if else blocks. If you look at my snippet I have it placed above the if else so you only have to have these lines of code written once

Comment: However you want to handle the increment is up to you but if you copy and paste my code snippet in your game and test it out maybe it will help understand the reasoning behind setting the count to 0 to start vs setting the count to 1

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane would've never realised it wasnt necessary to write the innerHTML inside the if/else statement if I hadnt seen it. I think I'll leave it my way cause I understand it better, even if the code repeats itself a little. Also, got the difference between the counters. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified function version of setting up multiple number guessing games on a single page. All game related data is kept in dataset attributes `num` and `try` of the associated input field.

```js
function guess(id){
 let el = document.getElementById(id);
 el.dataset.try=0;
 el.dataset.num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
 el.onchange=()=>el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML =
    "Attempt "+(++el.dataset.try)+":<br>Your guess is "
     +["too low.","correct!","too high."]
      [Math.sign(el.value-el.dataset.num)+1]              
}
guess('guess1');guess('guess2');
```

```html
  <h1>GUESS SOME NUMBERS:</h1>
  <p>Enter a guess:</p>
  <input type="number" id="guess1">
  <div></div>
  <p>Enter another guess:</p>
  <input type="number" id="guess2">
  <div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're redefining the attempt variable in a local scope as an integer which is overriding the reference to the document element. When you use "innerHTML" your using it on the localized attempt (an integer not the document element)

Try this:

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1

let result = document.querySelector(".result")
let attempt = document.querySelector(".attempt")
let button = document.getElementById("button")
let guess = document.getElementById("guess")


button.addEventListener("click", checkGuess)

let attemptCount = 1 // Renamed this from attempt and moved to global scope

function checkGuess() {
    let guessValue = document.getElementById("guess").value
    attempt.innerHTML = "Attempt n: " + attemptCount
    if (guessValue < randomNumber) {
        result.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low";
    } else if (guessValue > randomNumber) {
        result.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high";
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "You guessed correctly";
    }
    attemptCount++;
}
```

Comment: Incrementing the new variable won't have any affect since it gets redefined every click

Comment: This will always return an attempt count of 1 the attemptCount has to be delcared outside the function

Comment: Great call both of you, I wasn't looking for other issues in the code but I've corrected that now

Comment: Why the down vote? I answered the question "It doesn't show up on the page like "result" does." as the OP asked. The question wasn't "why doesn't it increment?" so I wasn't looking for such

Comment: Your answer still has bugs in it thats why the downvote. First you had the attemptCount scoped inside the function so it would always be 1. Currently in your answer you are only updating the attempt count text when the number is too low AND you are only incrementing the attempt count when the number is 2 high. There are 3 major bugs in your answer thats why the downvote, test on a codepen you will see

Comment: The ops question is 'I cant understand why attempt.innerHTML won't work. It doesn't show up on the page like "result" does.' I corrected the portion causing that error and educated the OP

Comment: And the solution isnt just the scoping of the counter, attempt.innerHTML will only work in your answer when the guess is too low since it is inside the if else block, so your answer is still wrong. It is a two part issue, put your code in a snippet or code pen and you will see

Comment: Another bug I noticed is you are incrementing the attemptCount after the if else block. This will show the wrong attemptCount because the innerHTML is updated before the attemptCount is incremented so it will always show a user the incorrect attempt count

Comment: That's false if starting at 1 as @GraceP was looking to do. First call is 1, attemptCount  is incremented after logic completes, next call is 2 etc.

Comment: You are correct when the counter is starting at 1, however starting the counter at 1 does not make a whole lot of sense to me. In this case I rescind my bug comment about incrementing however your text update of innerHTML is still wrong it wont display correctly when the guess is correct or too high

Comment: I always start at 0 and increment accordingly as well, but was just answering the way the OP asked. I updated based on your response, but again I was focused on answering the OPs question and not analyzing all aspects of the code as that wasn't the question. I answered what was being asked